# How to allocate memory with number of bytes stored in a register?

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls

Depending on an integer input from the user, I set the number of bytes needed and put the value in register $s7.

```
li $v0,9
lw $a0,$s7      
syscall
#store the memory address of allocated memory
```

However, when I try to run the code using MARS it says there is a syntax error on the second line.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get around this? I've also tried:

```
li $a0,$s7
```

UPDATE: I think I fixed it, I just needed:

```
lw $a0,($s7)
```

MIPS, I hate you.

UPDATE 2: I have another problem... If I try to save using sw with an offset, how might I do this?

```
sw $a0,$s7($s1)
```

gives me an error, putting $s7 in parenthesis won't get me out of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the updated question: Are you sure MIPS has a memory addressing mode such as `$r1($r2)`? Go over your tutorials and check (unless you use some extended version of MIPS that is often given as an assignment for implementation, and often leads to the strong feelings you describe above).

If not, as most RISC languages don't allow that, you'll have to find another way, more manual, to add $s1 and $s7. May I suggest `add`?